# Is this an old php syntax

Tags: php

I am looking at this code from a job interview and they are asking what will be the result. I tried running the code but I get a syntax error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 7

```
<?php
$x = 2;
$y = 4;
$z = 6;


if($z > $y > $x) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

The answer to this question is "false", however I can't even execute the script. So, is this an old syntax that is not supported in php 7 or just a wrong answer. In other words, is it better to say this is invalid syntax than saying it's false.

Comment: Maybe the greater than symbols are not valid. Also why should the answer be false?

Comment: I don't know. Here is where I got this from: https://www.upwork.com/i/interview-questions/php/

`At first glance, one would expect the boolean to evaluate to “true” because 6 > 4 > 2. However, the correct answer is “false” because PHP will first evaluate $z > $y, which returns a boolean value of 1 or true. It is this boolean value of 1 that is compared to the next integer in the chain, bool(1) > $z, which will result in NULL and echo “false.”`

Comment: It will indeed produce a syntax error on all versions: https://3v4l.org/tMZl1 edit: see the answer by @SandroMarques for the syntactically valid code

Comment: If I got that in as an interview question, I would just say that it's invalid syntax and leave it at that.

Comment: How did the interview go, if I may ask? I am curious now, since there has been no update. :P

Answer (score 4):

The right code should have parentesis in first evaluation of condition

```
<?php
$x = 2;
$y = 4;
$z = 6;


if(($z > $y) > $x) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

That is the same thing as

```
$x = 2;
$y = 4;
$z = 6;


if(true > $x) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably leave the answer as an incorrect syntax, and give the explanation as to why, and what the proper syntax would be, and what the expected result is.

In that way, you don't limit yourself to the question itself, but rather made the interviewers aware of your understanding at a programmatical level, as well as being able to give the logical answer to the equation.